# Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise - SQL Row Comparison

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, self-join

I'm querying a Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE) Database and need to compare rows i.e. row 1 with 2, 2 with 3 etc. I do not want to have to use Cursors for performance reasons. I am thinking that a self join is the answer but the ID's are not sequential i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 . I have tried creating a column in a temp table using the Row_Number function but it appears that the function is not supported. The below is the query that obtains the requisite data (without the self Join). Does anyone know to compare rows without using cursors in this situation?

```
SELECT h.HeaderIdS, w.WrapUpIdS, h.CallStarttimeDtTm, h.CallEndtimeDtTm, h.InvestorIdS, h.AdviserIdS, h.BadgeIdS, h.EmployerNoIdS, h.ContactTypeCdS, w.CallTypeCdS, w.SubTypeCdS, w.ProductCdS, h.TeamCodeCdS, h.ContactedByCdS,
h.AgentIdS, h.SystemTypeCdS
    INTO #tempHeader
    FROM WrapUpHeader h
--Criteria
INNER JOIN WrapUp w ON h.HeaderIdS = w.HeaderIdS And w.StatusCdS = 'Active'
WHERE  h.StatusCdS = 'Active'
AND h.CallStartTimeDtTm >= @FromDate
AND h.CallStartTimeDtTm < DateAdd(dd,1,@ToDate)
AND h.TeamCodeCdS = @BusinessUnit
AND ((h.AdviserIdS IS NULL) OR (h.AdviserIdS IS NOT NULL AND h.AdviserIdS <> @AdviserNo))
AND ((h.BadgeIdS IS NULL) OR (h.BadgeIdS IS NOT NULL AND h.BadgeIdS <> @DealerGroup))
AND ((h.EmployerNoIdS IS NULL) OR (h.EmployerNoIdS IS NOT NULL AND h.EmployerNoIdS <> @EmployerNo))
AND ((w.ProductCdS IS NULL) OR (w.ProductCdS IS NOT NULL AND w.ProductCdS <> @Product))   
AND ((w.CallTypeCdS IS NULL) OR (w.CallTypeCdS IS NOT NULL AND w.CallTypeCdS <> @CallType))   
AND ((w.SubTypeCdS IS NULL) OR (w.SubTypeCdS IS NOT NULL AND w.SubTypeCdS <> @SubType))   


SELECT  
        Distinct RTRIM(th.headerids) as 'CALLIDA',  
        th.callstarttimedttm as 'TimeA',
        RTRIM(th.investorids) as 'AccountIDA',
        RTRIM(e.entitynametxm) as 'StaffMemberA',
        Count(th.investorids) as 'RepeatCallA'

INTO #TABLEA
from #tempHeader tH 
inner join wrapupdetail d on d.wrapupids = th.wrapupids       
inner join entity e on e.entityids = th.agentids
left outer join notes note on note.contactids = th.headerids
left outer join ownershiptasks ot on note.OwnershipTasksIds =ot.OwnershipTasksIds
order by  th.investorids, th.callstarttimedttm
```

Comment: What do you mean with row 1? Is it the first callstarttimedttm for the smallest investorids?

Comment: this is how we create identity column in temp table `select *, id=identity(10) into #tmp from table1`